# SVA: Is it possible to disable SV property check from consequent side?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, verification, uvm, system-verilog-assertions

I have an SV property as below:

```
propert my_property;
@(posedge clk) disable iff(reset) (!s_of) throughout ($rose(halt) ##0 ((rx_prio) > (expec_prio)) ##[0:$] $rose(rdy)) |-> ##[1:100] (my_prio[rx_prio]==1'b1);
endproperty:my_property
```

I have the assertion as below:

```
MY_PROPERTY_CHECK:assert property (my_property)
else
$error;
```

In the above property, i have signal **s_of** which should not be asserted throughout the check. But the scenario here is, this signal **s_of** is getting asserted during the consequent of the implication operator. Hence, my requirement is to disable the check, even when the signal **s_of** is asserted during consequent statement. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Define what you mean by disable the check. Disable the execution to be able to start a new one or disable it only for one clock cycle?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding it in the `disable iff(...)`? Something like `disable iff(reset || s_of)`. This will disable the assertion whenever `s_of` goes HIGH, regardless of whether the antecedent or the consequent is currently being "executed".

Comment: Yes. I tried the `disable iff(reset_n || s_of)`. As the signal `s_of` is asserted at consequent part, the check goes to incomplete and stays in incomplete state till end of simulation.

Comment: Isn't this what you wanted? I mean if `s_of` goes HIGH and never goes low again, then you can't re-trigger the antecedent, so it makes sense for the check to stay incomplete.

Comment: yes. That is correct. But, if the check stays incomplete, it implies something phishy, because we can know its implication only after the analysis as to why the check is incomplete. So wanted a way to completely take it off from the waveform, just like the way, the check wont be present if antecedent is not satisfied.

Comment: My simulator treats a disable like this by setting the assert to 'disabled'. I agree that 'incomplete' has a different ring to it, but I'm guessing disabling the check is the only way to get it into the 'incomplete' state. If this is the case, then you shouldn't treat 'incompletes' as such a bad thing, because it means you explicitly wanted the check not to complete.

Comment: Point taken. For now, I'm keeping it to **disable** and check in  incomplete state is taken.

Thanks.